# What is the difference between passing a Map and using `body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST`

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

These two examples of encapsulated pipelines get their `pipelineParams` from two different methods, however it is not readily clear why one is preferable to the other.

What is the ramification of using

```
def call(body) {
    // evaluate the body block, and collect configuration into the object
    def pipelineParams= [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = pipelineParams
    body()

    pipeline {
        echo pipelineParams.name
    }
}
```

vs using

```
def call(Map pipelineParams) {
    pipeline {
        echo pipelineParams.name
    }
}
```

Example code from https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/10/02/pipeline-templates-with-shared-libraries/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that in the first case, using a pipeline looks like declarative configuration. It's a so-called [builder strategy](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/documentation/core-domain-specific-languages.html#section-delegatesto) in terms of DSL:

```
myDeliveryPipeline {
    branch = 'master'
    scmUrl = 'ssh://git@myScmServer.com/repos/myRepo.git'
    ...
}
```

Whereas in the second case, applying a pipeline looks like imperative code, i.e. it's a regular function call:

```
myDeliveryPipeline(branch: 'master', scmUrl: 'ssh://git@myScmServer.com/repos/myRepo.git', ...)
```

There is also explanation in [the official Jenkins doc](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-a-more-structured-dsl):

> There is also a “builder pattern” trick using Groovy’s Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST, which permits Jenkinsfile to look slightly more like a configuration file than a program, but this is more complex and error-prone and is not recommended.

Personally, I can't say that I'm not recommending the DSL approach. The doc doesn't recommend this because it's a bit more complex and can be error-prone